# softmax cross entropy derivative

Tags: derivatives, machine-learning

I am working with Logistics Regression with multiclass classfication(softmax with entropy):
$$L(w)=-\sum_{n}\sum_{k}y_{nk}log(\frac{e^{w_{k}^Tx_{n}}}{\sum_{i}e^{w_{i}^Tx_{n}}})$$
differentiation:
$$\frac{\partial L(w)}{\partial w_{j}}$$
$$-\sum_{n}\sum_{k}y_{nk}\frac{1}{p_{k}}\quad and\quad p_{k}=\frac{e^{w_{k}^Tx_{n}}}{\sum_{i}e^{w_{i}^Tx_{n}}}$$
when k = j
$$\frac{e^{w_{j}^Tx_{n}}\cdot \sum_{i}e^{w_{i}^Tx_{n}}-e^{w_{j}^Tx_{n}}\cdot e^{w_{k}^Tx_{n}}}{(\sum_{i}e^{w_{i}^Tx_{n}})^2}=p_{j}(1-p_{k})$$
$$
=-\sum_{n}y_{nj}\frac{1}{p_{j}}(p_{j}(1-p_{k}))x_{n}
$$
when k ${\neq}$ j

$$\frac{0\cdot \sum_{i}e^{w_{i}^Tx_{n}}-e^{w_{j}^Tx_{n}}\cdot e^{w_{k}^Tx_{n}}}{(\sum_{i}e^{w_{i}^Tx_{n}})^2}=-p_{j}p_{k}$$
$$=-\sum_{n}\sum_{k\neq j}y_{nk}\frac{1}{p_{k}}\cdot -(p_{j}p_{k})x_{n}$$

Question 1 : Please explain how $\sum_{i}e^{w_{i}^Tx_{n}}$ works when under differentiation for case i=j and i${\neq}$j?
after that combine everythings:
$$=-\sum_{n}y_{nj}\frac{1}{p_{j}}(p_{j}(1-p_{k}))x_{n}+\sum_{n}\sum_{k\neq j}y_{nk}\frac{1}{p_{k}}(p_{j}p_{k})x_{n}$$
Question 2 : How to further simplification?

The result should be :
$$\sum_{n}(p_{j}-y_{nj})x_{n}$$
Of course I am not sure the index is right or not
Can someone help me please?